# Ansible ad-hoc - fix integer being passed as a string (I think) when being used a variable

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook for building VMware VMs using the Ansible vmware_guest module. This module requires the RAM value to be a integer and in MB.

I have a template in Ansible Tower that allows me to pass the value for RAM as an integer and my playbook does the maths. I think this is based on Jinja maths. Here's the link I found for maths - [How to use arithmetic when setting a variable value in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33505521/how-to-use-arithmetic-when-setting-a-variable-value-in-ansible)

This is the variable in my playbook **memory_mb: "{{ VM_RAM * 1024 }}"**. When using Ansible Tower this works perfectly. A user can ask for 8GB of RAM and the playbook does the conversion from GB to MB.

I currently have a requirement to build VMs from an ad-hoc command. I believe the command below should work, but it seems the "VM_RAM" variable is being picked up as a string. Running the command gives me an error - **"msg": "A specified parameter was not correct: configSpec.memoryMB"**.

```
ansible-playbook vm-build.yml --extra-vars '{"VM_name":"new-vm", "VM_HDD2":"10", "VM_CPU":"4", "VM_RAM":"8"}'
```

Can anyone see where I am mistaken, or have any suggestions? I should add, I don't want to do the conversion in the ad-hoc command. Can I force the ad-hoc command to use a integer?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the `""`s aboud `8` in `"VM_RAM":"8"`? Dropping it suggest it to be an integer value, is not it?

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out.

Added "|int" to the playbook to change from a string to integer after the ad-hoc command is run.

```
Before: memory_mb: "{{ VM_RAM * 1024 }}"
```

```
After: memory_mb: "{{ VM_RAM |int * 1024 }}"
```